# Two rf 433 transmiter and one receiver connection won't work?

Tags: rf, transceiver

This is my problem. I want to transmit from two transmitters and capture data with a single receiver. I bought two pairs of [rf433](http://rayshobby.net/cart/433-rf) and  was able to transmit data between each of these rx-tx pairs correctly with ardunio.

But sending from two tx and receiving by one rx was unable to accomplish. Then I tried to find out the reason and here is what I found. These rx and tx modules wont work vice versa. See this diagram:

[image]

Since they both transmit 433Mz this also *should* work fine. If they work in vice versa only, I am able to transmit from two tx.

But I am unable to find out the reason behind this. I would be very thankful if anyone can help with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the part number or the link of the RF devices.

Comment: @Umar these are the rf modules http://rayshobby.net/cart/433-rf

Comment: Are you attempting to transmit simultaneously the exact same data from two transmitters?

Comment: No not simultaneously only at a given time. can you help me with this problem? why can't they communicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transmitters don't transmit at exactly the same frequency - there may be tens of kHz difference - the receiver however is matched to the transmitter and, from what I know and have read about these particular devices, there is a manual adjuster on the receiver to bring it into near-perfect alignment with the transmitter it is paired with.

[image]

Notice the screw terminal on the receiver - this is, I believe, an adjuster that can align the receiver's operating frequency with the transmitter. Basically this means that two randomly chosen transmitters are unlikely to be at the same frequency and, as a result, one setting of the screw on the receiver will not suit both transmitters.

They are $5 a pair so you get what you pay for.

Comment: [Are you sure?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74272/how-to-connect-20-wireless-sensors-in-one-receiver-with-arduino) I found that on stack overflow. Any idea?

Comment: yes you are right. i tested it now. Thank you very much for the information...

Comment: @Priyankara generally a more expensive receiver will lock onto a slightly different frequency across maybe a 1MHz bandwidth especially those that use FM. The units you have are kind of an exception and with no data sheet to tell otherwise it's just bad luck that they won't work as you expected.