# Creating a LoRaWAN gateway with multiple nodes?

Tags: arduino, rf, sensor, lora

I'm working with a project to collect temperature data from about 50 cabins that are located close together. It therefore seems easiest to use 50 Lora nodes with temperature sensors and one gateway.

So I'm searching for a way to use multiple Lora nodes to create a sensor network. From what I've gathered it might be more cost and time effective to buy a readymade gateway such the Dragino. But I can't seem to find any good guides on how to create a small Lora node? I live in Europe and therefore want to use 433Hz frequency. I'm thinking something like a RFM96 and an Arduino nano should do the trick? Or is there easier solutions?

Since there is little documentation about this I hope others can find this useful as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you need is an RFM96 or RFM95, any microcontroller with SPI, a suitable antenna and power source + sensors. You don't have to implement the whole LoRaWAN protocol. You can treat the RFM96 just as a "stupid" radio and send custom frames using LoRa modulation.

Comment: @filo This sounds great! Could you please send some documentation for this or point me in the right direction? I think I solve the "RFM96/95 + MCU + battery + sensor" part but to where do these sensor nodes send their data?

Comment: Have you got a supply of power in the cabins or do you intend the transmitting radios to be battery powered?

Comment: @Andyaka They are to be battery powered.

Comment: And do you only require data to be sent in one direction? If so how often and what size of data? I.e. if you only need to transmit temperature (3 bytes of data) once per hour then there will be a better solution for battery power rather than LoRa

Comment: @Andyaka Yes only in one direction. Only temperature and possibly battery levels. I think sending data every hour or every second hour should be more than enough. What solutions do you recommend? My initial thought was to use ESP8266 with a temperature sensor and battery as there is WiFi in every cabin but these modules draw quite some battery so the batteries will have to be changed every 6 months or so by my calculations.

Comment: @Lamar I took the liberty of posting a suggestion based on a design I did years ago using 433 MHz (the application was a hall full of food freezers that needed monitoring from a central point).

Comment: @Lamar To make a prototype you could try the low power Arduino clone: Moteino + RFM69 Lora module. The Lora module is already assembled. You only have to solder the headers pins and play with it!
https://lowpowerlab.com/shop/product/159

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if......

The 50 cabins each send temperature data once every 10 minutes using battery power this *could* be handled by a system that does not rely on a receive protocol to tell the "transmitter" when to transmit. This *could* massively sustain battery life because you are not wasting several mA of current continuously keeping the radio listening.

In the 9 minutes, 59.9 seconds between transmissions your battery consumption could be as low as a few microamps. During transmission (0.1 seconds) you might need 20 mA so the average current is: -

Background (say 10 uA) plus 20 mA/6600 = 10 uA + 3 uA = 13 uA.

Channel usage per cabin transmitter is 0.1 seconds every 660 seconds so, with 50 transmitters this means the channel average utilization is 5/660 = 0.75%. Each transmitter could randomly time its transmission based on a unique address so that on average it was ten minutes (with plus or minus 5 minutes as the random factor).

Collision probability would be low but you'd get a cabin's temperature the next time in all probability. It's all down to how you want to play it.

This type of system would use 50 transmitters and one receiver. The receiver does all the data collection for the 50 cabins.

Quite cheap (I would use FM) transmitters could be used but each would need a little MCU to format the transmission with preamble, address, payload data and checksum. The little MCU would also do the random timing thing.

The receiver (AC powered) would convert a received transmission back to the payload data (having proven that the checksum tallied) and the address of the cabin would also be detected in the transmission.

[Similar question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74272/how-to-connect-20-wireless-sensors-in-one-receiver-with-arduino/74281)

*Maybe a LoRa module could be put into shut-down mode to conserve battery life thus you get a similar solution that wouldn't require an MCU to format the data to make it suitable for a transmission?*

Comment: This could absolutely work! What do you recon the range of such FM transmitters to be? And what FM receiver that could receive multiple transmissions could you recommend for a start?

Comment: Firstly, you can't receive multiple transmissions. This idea is based on a transmission getting through to the receiver because the overall channel occupancy is low and each transmitter randomly times its transmission. I got 100 metres from quite small FM modules. I'll try and find a recommendation....

Comment: I don't think they make the Tx and Rx I used back in the 1990s but [here's](http://www.radiometrix.com/our-products/433MHz/TX) a link to their current portfolio. Basically you choose a transmitter and a receiver. See what you think then come back if you need more selection help. I think you should look at the TX2 and RX2 that they offer.